# Uma API Rest é uma combinação de .EXE com .DLL's?

Tags: api, rest, http-request, dll, .exe

Eu gostaria de saber exatamente como funciona uma API Rest quanto aos arquivos que fazem parte dela.
Vejam se meu entendimento está correto:
Quando ela está no servidor, funcionando, haverá um arquivo .EXE em execução escutando uma determinada porta para receber requests, é isso?
Ela receberá requests pelo executável, e este poderá utilizar classes, métodos, etc. que estão nas .DLL's?
A API se comunica com outros programas do computador, ou somente com os que ela tem previsão de se comunicar?

Enfim, várias perguntas, porém o ponto principal é saber se há um arquivo executável rodando no servidor recebendo requests, ou se as requests podem ser passadas diretamente para uma DLL.

Answer (score 2):

APIs Rest são serviços consumidos através do protocolo Http. O consumo dessas APIs é feito por um *cliente*, que pode ser um código Javascript, um executável, uma Dll... qualquer programa que consiga fazer uma requisição Http.

As APIs fazem parte de uma aplicação Web, hospedada em um servidor (IIS, Apache, etc).
Elas podem ser construídas em várias linguagens, dentre elas .NET, PHP e Java. No caso do .NET por exemplo, envolve o uso de Dll's, então, tudo depende da linguagem utilizada.

Enfim, respondendo a sua pergunta, não é uma simples Dll que recebe e interpreta as requisições. É necessário criar e publicar uma aplicação no formato Web, usando uma linguagem que tenha a capacidade de gerar APIs Rest.